# Inject Github Actions environmental variable into script

Tags: github, github-actions

We are trying to setup our CI so that we get the Github Ref into our code.

We've tried the following in our Workflow file:

```
- run: GITHUB_REF="${GITHUB_REF}" CI=true yarn test:pact:consumer
```

But it doesn't do much:

[image]

We've tried the following also:

```
GITHUB_REF="$GITHUB_REF" CI=true yarn test:pact:consumer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following two, and in both cases the value seems to be passed to script.

- In github action yaml

```yaml
      - run: GITHUB_REF="${GITHUB_REF}" CI=true yarn foo 
      - run: GITHUB_REF=${{ github.ref }} CI=true yarn foo
```

- `foo.js`

```js
console.log('process.env.GITHUB_REF: ', process.env.GITHUB_REF)
```

- In `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
      "foo": "node foo.js"
  }
```

- result

[image]

Comment: For some banana weird reason copying and pasting your code just magically made it work.